# 382 - J2EE Bad Practices: System.exit()

Tags: java

Is there any chance of calling System.exit() from ExecutorService.shutdown() method ? I'm getting below appscan finding on my code which has no call for System.exit() but it call shutdown()  method of ExecutorService .

Severity    Classification  Vulnerability   API CWE
High    Definitive  AppDOS.Shutdown java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.shutdown   382 - J2EE Bad Practices: System.exit()

Comment: What does the javadoc say? Does it say that this method will exist the JVM? What do you conclude?

Comment: Does your code use an ExecutorService? If so, is it one of the standard JRE provided ones or is it a custom one, perhaps provided by a third party library?

Comment: No . java doc didn't say that it call System.exit() but also I'm not getting any refernce to confirm that no System.exit() call has been made.

Comment: yes , My code used ExecutorService and it is standard JRE implementation .

Comment: @Raj: the javadoc tells what the method does. It it had the huge side-effect of exiting the JVM, it would tell it.

Comment: thanks JB. I agree your thought .

Answer (score 0):

@Raj: the javadoc tells what the method does. It it had the huge side-effect of exiting the JVM, it would tell it. –  JB Nizet 14 mins ago